# Only one ajax call, wait until success until next click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do prevent like if a user clicks alot of times on a link that runs a ajax call, that it only run again after the it has been succeed

Comment: why not paste some code that you're starting from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to add a class to the link when the user clicks, and remove the class when the response is received.

Each click of the link checks to see if the `pending` class exists, and only sends the AJAX request if not.

Then the `complete:` callback removes the `pending` class.

```
$('a.myLink').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    if( !$th.hasClass('pending') ) {
        $th.addClass('pending');
        $.ajax({
          url:'something',
          complete: function() {
              $th.removeClass('pending');
          }
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you could also use jQuery.data() to attach this 'pending' data value
See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @Dancrumb - That's true. Nice thing about adding a class is that you can use it to provide the user some visual feedback to show that the link isn't clickable. I'd bet that it is a faster operation than accessing `.data()` as well. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

if you mean what I think you mean, then as soon as the button is clicked you'd disable the button in your ajax function (before you get to the actual making of an http request). Then once your ajax call is complete your `onreadystate` function would re-enable it.

to disable a button, if it has an id.

```
document.getElementById("theidofthebutton").enabled = false;
```

to re enable it...

```
document.getElementById("theidofthebutton").enabled = true;
```

Edit:  I see you're refering to a link not a button.  I could be wrong but I think you can still disable in the same way.

Comment: MrVimes - I was thinking you may be on to something about disabling the link, but I did a quick test. Doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/KkYCm/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jquery plugin [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element) to block the user from clicking the link again. This can be done at the Element or Page level.

```
// unblock when ajax activity stops 
$(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 

function test() { 
    $.ajax({ url: 'wait.php', cache: false }); 
} 

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#pageDemo2').click(function() { 
        $('div.test').block({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' }); 
        test(); 
    });  
});
```